# How to version large binary files?

Tags: git, version-control, binary-files

I run Windows XP inside a virtual machine for some tasks.  I attempted to use git to version the image for virtual box; however, it is about 6GB after all the service packs.  I only have 6GB of ram and git bombs out saying it is out of memory.

I would basically like to have snapshots of Windows so that I can simply blow away an image and start anew when I want to.  I like to have something I can rollback to in the event that an upgrade doesn't work so I would prefer to use version control or snapshots if the filesystem supports it.

Any ideas on what tools I can use to do that?

Comment: Related - [Version control for binary files](http://superuser.com/questions/105048/version-control-for-binary-files)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best guess is to use virtualization software features. For example Virtualbox [supports snapshotting](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#snapshots). That's pretty effective way for achieving what you described.

VMWare Workstation [supports exactly the same functionality](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_preserve_using_sshot.html).

Comment: I will have to give that a try, it does support differencing which is what I want.  It'll be a simple change for my backup process, instead of git commands, I can just use rsync to setup mirrors.